# How to fail the sequence container if the tasks in the container can not be all executed?

Tags: ssis

I am working on a package, the function for this container is if it fail it will be directed to another way based on the condition tasks set in the sequence container. I used the expression as the precedence constraint execution condition and expect if the value got from the execute SQL task does not match the condition, not execute the next task. However, the sequence container does not fail if all the tasks do not completely execute. (attached the status below)Are there any way that I can fail the sequence container if all the tasks in the sequence container can not be executed?

[statupic]https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OP1_0LvHEb0eT77TGSg-Fu2QX4eOkuAX

Comment: the link is not available

Comment: You can fail. I use the Script Task for it in which I add one line of code: `Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;`

Comment: @Arthur This should be a good way. But I set up another step to make it work. Thanks